# bootstrap form editor , how to edit saved form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using [Bootstrap Form Builder](http://bootsnipp.com/forms)
to build the forms which I save in database, Now when it comes to form edit, I am able to load the previous saved forms from db on page, However event handlers wont work on the loaded content(click on respective field to edit the name,id type)? even if its not an ajax request where we need to reattach event handlers after completing ajax request, They do not have enough documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [kevinchappell Form Builder](https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder) which offer great customization, we can also edit previously created forms that are saved in db